# Azure APIM Validate-Content Inbound policy, Validate Request Body

Tags: .net, azure, validation, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I have api's in APIM, i need to validate request payload body(Json Format) foreach Post Request.

I followed steps from this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validation-policies#attributes

I have added proper json schema in Schemas :-
[image]

and i have added below policy in Inbound policy, mentioned **schemaid** with the above created schema.

```
 <validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="102400" size-exceeded-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="requestBodyValidation">
        <content type="application/json" validate-as="json" action="detect" schema-id="Postschema" />
    </validate-content>
```

Even after following above steps, if i make request with invalid json, i am still receiving 200 success response. What am i missing?

Comment: Please use 'prevent' instead of 'detect' action. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validation-policies#actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the action `detect` to `prevent` for content-type `application/json`.

You can also change the action to `detect` for `unspecified-content-type-action` if you want to allow requests without content-type `application/json`.

[Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validation-policies#actions):

> **detect**: Log validation errors, without interrupting request or response processing.

> **prevent**: Block the request or response processing, log the verbose validation error, and return an error. Processing is interrupted when the first set of errors is detected.

```xml
<validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="102400" size-exceeded-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="requestBodyValidation">
        <content type="application/json" validate-as="json" action="prevent" schema-id="Postschema" />
</validate-content>
```