# azure api management (apim) schema validation case sensitive

Tags: azure, apim

I am currently using validate-content to validate the request body against api spec. when I set action="prevent" and allow-additional-properties="false", it is returns error when I pass property name with a different case in the request body. What can I do to ignore the case?

I tried to set action to detect and go through the error list detect but did not work

Comment: Please share the policy you tried

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, **`validate-content`** validates the definition of the schema including the case of properties and types.

You can ignore the case of the property by using `action="detect"` which will not interrupt request or response processing but you will get the error message in Trace.

***I have used the below policy***-

```xml
<validate-content  unspecified-content-type-action="prevent"  max-size="102400"  size-exceeded-action="prevent"  errors-variable-name="requestBodyValidation"> 
<content  type="application/json"  validate-as="json"  action="detect"  schema-id="myschema"  allow-additional-properties="false"  />  
</validate-content>
```

In my schema, property ***name*** is in small case but while testing I am passing below request body.

```json
{
"Name": "Afreen"
}
```

***I am getting 200 OK result.***

[image]

But you can see the detail execution of `validate-content` in trace.

[image]

***References***-
[.net - Azure APIM Validate-Content Inbound policy, Validate Request Body - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72470331/azure-apim-validate-content-inbound-policy-validate-request-body).

Comment: Yes, I tried with similar policy. I just want to know if there is a way to make property validation case-insensitive? So, you should be able to pass "Name/name/naMe" but, it should throw error if I pass property "dummyName"

Comment: @VikramSudhini I believe it is not feasible as per ms docs. If you need more details on this feature, you can check with the product team

Comment: By using Detect, it will not break the flow but you will get the error in Trace or you can make allow-additional-properties=true